# Download control board software simulators

Tags: c, embedded

I am interested in learning how to do embedded system programming in c. However, I will need some hardware.

I am wondering is there any software that can simulate what the control board will do?

The control board is listed in the following tutorial

http://www.learn-c.com/hardware.htm

Many thanks for any advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The board you linked to is *not* an embedded system board, it is an I/O interface for a PC.  If you want to simulate that, you can simply write PC code stubs for the I/O functions that simulate connected devices' behaviour.  However, you will not learn much about embedded systems from this.  You may learn a little about PC based control, but since the board does not support interrupts or DMA, I suggest again that you will not learn much of that either.

Moreover the board is designed for an ISA bus slot.  Modern PCs no longer have such slots.  And modern operating systems prevent access to hardware I/O in user level code.

If you are serious about learning embedded systems development, you might for example download Keil's [MDK-ARM](http://www.keil.com/arm/mdk.asp) evaluation; it includes an ARM simulator with on-chip peripheral simulation for a number of commonly available ARM based micro-controllers, and real hardware is available at reasonable cost.

If PC based control is of more interest, then you would be better off starting with a USB based I/O device, such as [this example](http://www.maplin.co.uk/Module.aspx?ModuleNo=42857&C=SO&U=strat15).

Comment: The MDK-ARM simulator seems interesting. I am new at embedded systems. And this is just a hobby of mine. As I like using c programming. However, is there any usefull tutorials that help you get started programming with the MDK-ARM? Many thanks.

Comment: @robUK: http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/gsac/, http://www.keil.com/arm/man/arm.htm