# Starter kit for Embedded linux programming

Tags: c, linux, embedded

I want to begin learning embedded linux development (i'm not beginner in C nor in Linux) and i choose this book :
[http://www.amazon.com/Embedded-Linux-Primer-Practical-Real-World/dp/0137017839](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137017839)

If you have a better choice let me know please.

I want to buy some hardware to do some practice, any suggestions?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have a look at the [Beagle Board](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BeagleBoard)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting into Embedded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229822/getting-into-embedded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux programming is linux programming, even kernel level, so the question is what Luke asked.  What is it that you really want to do?  The computer you typed this question on may suffice for much of what you are interested in or none of it.  Depends.

If you go beagleboard avoid the old one go for the xM, it is usable where the other just costs more money to make it usable.  The raspberry pi should be out any time now but it is an unknown quanity.  I didnt like the plug computer but did like the open-rd board, liked it much better than my beagleboard.  I have one of the chinese clones of the beagleboard which I liked much better (because it was usable out of the box) the xM has bridged that gap though.  embeddedarm.com has a number of boards.  The hawkboard is fine as well, they have had that picture up about pcb design flaw forever but my boards so far are fine.

Oh the open-rd board has sata built in you can plug a laptop hard drive right into the board, all of the others use slow usb or flash based solutions (the open-rd might be a usb to sata though).  there is a tegra2 based one out there with various flavors that did that usb to sata, pretty lame.  The big problem with these arm based one is they use slow mass storage and you cant really take advantage of the instruction set or other things like that, they are also crippled with the amount of ram.

There is always qemu, its free and you can try different processors.  I would make sure you put ARM on the list of things you want to try/learn but might be worth trying others as well, mips, ppc, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, can you tell me if there a starter kit that i can buy to learn (beagle board or other).

Comment: I would call the beagleboard (or the open-rd) a start kit itself.  Add the power supply and maybe serial cable and a few things you might not have.  Their web pages and/or downloads are full of howtos for many things, how to load ubuntu on the board how to load fedora, how to update uboot, how to boot from sd how to boot from usb, etc.  Before buying anything, surf around the various websites first and see if it covers things at the level you are interested in.

Comment: Looking at the description of the book you linked and your answer about building the kernel first.  the beagleboard xM is probably where you want to start. (or qemu or just use a spare PC/laptop)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, if i choose the beagle board-XM : http://www.liquidware.com/shop/show/BB-XM/BeagleBoard+XM, do i need another things to start with (i mean cables and other...) or it's ok?

Comment: You are going to need to do your research on this one...How is it powered?  Can you power it from the usb otg port or do you need a wall wart? (probably the usb otg but check that).  What are the boot options, I dont think it has flash onboard like the older BB, will it do everything from one sd card?  full sized, mini or micro? you are going to need a computer with a serial port, the usb to serial things are fine, 10 bucks or so, do you need a null modem adapter?  Is it a 1/100/1000baseT ethernet and do you have the right cable and hub/switch?  Etc.

Comment: Whether or not $150 is a lot of money or a little depending on your perspective you should do your research on this before purchasing.  Playing with linux is a time consuming hobby, the materials (source code and compilers) are free, the expense comes with the time you spend, this hardware goes along with that project, put the hours in researching this.  You will need a serial port and eventually will want ethernet, you will want an sd card and likely some usb media, a thumb drive with a few gig or a usb hard drive thing with dozens or more gig.

Comment: You "can" certainly cross compile linux completely, the linux folks in my department and our customers do it all the time, no need to simulate an arm host in qemu.  Now making an ubuntu distro though that is better suited to a qemu environment if you dont already have a full blown arm platform.  Do you have the hard drive space and a computer fast enough to do those builds without it taking an eternity (you can try this now without waiting for hardware).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply and all this advices :)

Answer (score 4):

@Greg - not a duplicate. Clearly this post is looking for advice on embedded linux, not general embedded.

@funnyCoder - What sorts of things are you wanting to do? Beagleboard is nice but might not fit your needs. Are you looking for:

- Battery powered
- Video display
- USB host capability
- Running a full desktop environment
- Removable storage
- Expansion ability
- Ethernet
- Wireless (Bluetooth or 802.11 or Zigbee)
- Buttons, switches, LEDs
- Touch screen interface
- Audio

Also, processor speed and RAM have a big influence on what you will be able to do. There are low-end systems and very high-end systems and lots in between. Give us some requirements and we can direct you a little better. Or maybe someone has a link to a comparison guide.

A good book I'd recommend is the O'Riley book [Building Embedded Linux Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529686), but the one you've got is pretty good too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, at first I want just to learn to compile a kernel and load it on the embedded device and later do some stuff in networking area.

Comment: Without more details, I can't recommend anything specific. [Here's](http://www.linuxfordevices.com/c/a/Linux-For-Devices-Articles/Teeny-weeny-Linux-SBCs/) a list of some available devices. The aforementioned Beagleboard is a good choice for a pretty full-featured system.

Comment: Thanks i will buy a beagle board, i think it's the best choice :)